# Can't stop home redirect routing for already logged user

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I’m developing a web app with angular 6, that has a login. Each user has a role and a route for each of those.

This is my routes system.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: LoginComponent },
  // {path:'register', component: RegisterComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},

  // Paths userTypeOne
  {path:'usertypeone', canActivate:[AuthGuard], data: { expectedUserType: 'userTypeOne'}, component: userTypeOneComponent, children: [
    {path:'dashboard-userTypeOne', component: DashboardUserTypeOneComponent}
  ]},

  // Paths del userTypeTwo
  {path:'usertypetwo', canActivate:[AuthGuard], data: { expectedUserType: 'userTypeTwo'}, component: userTypeTwoComponent, children: [
    {path:'dashboard-usertypetwo', component: DashboardUserTypetwoComponent}
  ]},

...
```

My problem is that I read a bunch of documentation but I don’t know how to implement that when the user changes the URL directly to mydomain.com/ (path: ‘’), it goes to the same URL (mydomain.com/role) if he’s logged or to the login (path: ‘’) if he’s not.

Right now my logic is: The user enters his username and password and it goes through a canActivate:[AuthGuard] function. There it authenticates the connection. If it’s valid it checks the ‘expectedUserType’ in the ‘data’ of the route and tries to match it with the userType from the ‘user’ that is connected (in localStorage). If it’s not a match is redirects to login, if it is it goes to the route for that specific userType.

How can I implement that? How to make the route check if it tries to log in even if it is already logged in, stops it and redirects to the userType dashboard? I hope it's understandable.

Here's my CanActivate

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        if(this.authService.loggedIn()){
            let json = JSON.parse(localStorage.user);
            this.userType = json.userType;
            if(this.userType != next.data.expectedUserType){
                this.authService.logout();
                this.flashMessage.show(`${next.data.expectedUserType} out of your reach`, {
                    cssClass: 'alert-success',
                    timeout: 3000
                  });
                  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                  return false;
            }
            return true
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['']);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your question is that you want to stop the user from accessing the login page if he is already logged in and the redirect the user to its specific page depending on the type of user.

You can do the following in the login component's constructor:

```
let user = JSON.parse(localstorage.user);
if(user) {
  if(user.userType == 'userTypeOne') { this.router.navigate(['usertypeone']); }
  if(user.userType == 'userTypeOne') { this.router.navigate(['usertypetwo']); }
}
```

So if the user object exists in the localstorage that means the user is logged in. So our component will check the usertype and redirect the user to his specific component.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Genius, I didn't know I could use the constructor for anything else than `private router: Router, bla bla bla`. I see my url changing to /login but then redirecting very quickly to /userTypeSomething. This does it for now. Thank you very much for the quick answer.

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped.